# Statistics on the number of PhD/postdoc by Professor across fields/universities/countries?

Tags: supervision, statistics, lab-management

I am wondering whether there are some available sources for statistics on the average number of PhD students and postdocs by Professor/supervisor across different fields, universities or countries?

I have the impression that some fields/universities favor a "chair" or "lab" system where one Professor supervises a large number of PhD and postdocs students, whereas others have a more "department" style with more Professors, but I haven't found any data/study that discusses this aspect?

Related yet distinct discussions on Academia:

- [How many PhD students does a typical STEM professor graduate during their entire career?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17461/how-many-phd-students-does-a-typical-stem-professor-graduate-during-their-entire)
- [How many PhD students are too many?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/103473/how-many-phd-students-are-too-many)
- [Is it normal for universities to limit the number of PhD students a professor can supervise?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/159709/is-it-normal-for-universities-to-limit-the-number-of-phd-students-a-professor-ca)

Comment: Funding constraints (which have country, field, and local factors) are very important.

Comment: Overall statistics are probably meaningless. There would be a vast difference, I think, between math and, say, organic chemistry. Moreover, in the lab situation, advising may be a shared responsibility. A PI there might be the advisor of record, but with little actual contact.