# How can unaffilitated individuals sign up for Web of Knowledge / Science?

Tags: literature-search, web-of-science

I am conducting a meta-analysis of literature and several individuals recommended that I use *Web of Knowledge*, instead of just Google Scholar. The specific part of it I would need would be *Web of Science*.

I am not affiliated with any institution; I'm just an independent researcher. I don't see any option to sign up?

On the sign-in page it says:

> NOT REGISTERED?
>
> Take advantage of many great features when you register.
>
> ```
> Access Web of Science from outside your institution using **roaming** capabilities
> Set up citation alerts whereby you are notified by email when an article on your Alerts list has been cited
> ```
>
> Learn more about the benefits of registering for an account

However, when I follow the ["Learn more" link](https://clarivate.com/products/web-of-science/) I don't see any option to sign up and there are no further mentions of this "roaming" option.

Comment: Probably, like with many other products not usually marketed at the general public, you'd  use the "Contact is" link to ask them.

Comment: I originally misunderstood the "roaming" feature to sound like individual access, but I see now it just means remote access for institutional users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as @Anyon suggested in a comment, email their contact form to see if they have a practical solution for you.

If that doesn't help, then I don't have a definitive solution to your very real problem, but I can point you to some possibilities that come from the fantastic article, "[You’re a Researcher Without a Library: What Do You Do?](https://medium.com/a-wikipedia-librarian/youre-a-researcher-without-a-library-what-do-you-do-6811a30373cd)":

- Go to your closest local university library. Their onsite wifi network might give you the online access you need. (I suspect from your related question [[Meta-analysis using Google Scholar - are all years equally complete?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/130509/meta-analysis-using-google-scholar-are-all-years-equally-complete]) that you might want to scrape the site, so you might need wifi guest access within the building to do that.)
- If there is no nearby university library, try the largest nearby local library and see if they have access.
- Try to get some sort of research affiliate status with a university, perhaps by finding an academic coauthor.

Sorry, but I cannot recommend the options in that article of questionable legality.

Best wishes; I feel your pain and hope you work something out! Please update your question with an epilogue if you do find a solution; I'm sure it will help a lot of people in your situation!