# Post PHD carrer life

Tags: phd, computer-science

I wanted to ask what is the path of academic person that finished his Ph.D. in math or in Computer science what is the academic path that he can take?

Not everyone can continue with Academia or be part of the universities faculty, so does this mean the end of an academic career or can he continue learning post Ph.D. degrees?
What is the usual path of post Ph.D. in these fields?

Comment: Why do you think learning stops after a PhD?

Comment: @SolarMike: I mean academic learning, academic path

Comment: Are you tied to a particular country or city? In the US, there is plenty of opportunity to do R&D or things similar to R&D for private companies -- some of these are just as interesting as university research (and others are about maximizing clicks on ads). But things vary a lot by location.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the usual path of post Ph.D. in these fields?

There are two main options:

- Pursue in academia as a postdoc, usually in the hope of eventually reaching a tenured academic position.
- Apply for industry positions, either for research-oriented jobs (often found in big companies R&D departments or innovative start-ups) or non-research jobs for which PhD skills are required or recommended.

So if by "continue learning" OP means "keep doing research", there are options outside academia. Personally I often encourage PhD students who are close to graduating and haven't made their mind up to consider applying for a postdoc: it's a short contract which gives you a taste of the academic career path while also giving you a job experience, thus leaving all the doors open.

[This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/what-ratio-of-phd-graduates-in-stem-fields-ultimately-end-up-as-tenured-profes/) might help clarify the landscape of post-PhD options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to stop learning, or studying. But the way you go about it will probably change. Prior to earning a doctorate, you are under the direction of others and guided by them. Most people are, in any case.

But, having earned a doctorate, you become one of the guiders, not the guided. You can learn by developing ideas and sharing them with others. This is research. It is also fundamental to advising.

But, you also gain the opportunity for collaborative learning if you expand your circle of professional relationships. Thus, a group of people, whether co-located or not, can collectively study deep problems and learn from one another.

And, of course, in many fields, you can study on your own, once you get the experience to be your own guide.