# Sociology PhD : what are the prospects of landing a job within academia?

Tags: job, tenure-track, humanities

What are the job prospects, like the likelihood of becoming a university professor, for people who pursue a Ph.D. in sociology in North America?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/what-ratio-of-phd-graduates-in-stem-fields-ultimately-end-up-as-tenured-profes

Comment: This will depend very much on the particular student, the PhD program, the students ability and performance in the PhD program, and unpredictable random factors.   Furthermore, past outcomes may not be at all predictive of outcomes for future students.   Thus statistics of the form "x% of entering PhD students ended up in tenure track positions 10 years later" should be taken with a grain of salt by anyone considering entering a PhD program now.

Comment: @Brian Borchers very true, but an order of magnitude estimate would still be informative. I suspect many PhD students believe their chance is closer to 0.1 than 0.001.

Comment: @BrianBorchers, the *likelihood* does not depend on any particular student. I suspect the OP asks for the probability: (number of PhD-graduates-seeking-academic-post)/(number of new-positions).

Comment: @Dilworth I don't think there's any sensible number for that ratio as the numerator is heavily influenced by the denominator.